# Word for someone or something deeper than most would assume

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, personality

I was looking for a word to describe someone and I'm certain it exists... to describe a person is usually assumed to be one-dimensional but is in fact not, or even something more literal like a deceptively deep body of water. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for ***profound*** ?: 1)   Having, showing, or requiring great insight or understanding: *a profound thinker*; 2) Situated at, extending to, or coming from a great depth; deep.

Comment: It's common to say that something or someone "has hidden depths", and it has exactly the meaning you're looking for.  (But not for actual water of actually surprising depth, ironically...)

Answer (score 10):

You can consider:

**[there's more to someone/something than meets the eye](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/there%27s-more-to-someone/something-than-meets-the-eye?q=there%27s%20more%20to%20someone%2Fsomething%20than%20meets%20the%20eye)**

> A person or situation is more complex or interesting than they appear. (Oxford)

It's an idiom, not a single word. But it applies to both some*one* and some*thing*, as required.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe 'still waters run deep' or 'there's more to a book than its cover'.

Answer (score 3):

[+amgD]

"Sleeper."

I didn't know of this term until 1996, when I was working towards my CSPA A-CoP (most basic level of skydiving "licence" in Canada, issued by the Canadian Sport Parachuting Association), Buck Whalley--operator of "Mile High Parachuting" used this remark referring to my "until-then-beknownst-even-to-myself" skydiving-related aptitudes.

When I asked what the term meant, he said it to refer to a kind of car, such as a "muscle car that doesn't look/appear at first glance to be one of any remarkable power" (my own paraphrasing).

I don't know of how common or uncommon it is as a colloquialism in English, but perhaps that makes "Sleeper" itself a "sleeper" when it comes to terms q;-)

(As an epilogue, I've since had two cut-away malfunctions that could have been vastly mitigated with more care on my part and haven't skydive'n since 2005... q:-D)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "depth" literally, we might say:

- Be careful when you get into the water. Most people **underestimate the depth** at this point.
- The beach looks perfectly safe but **it is deceiving**. Many a swimmer has been taken by the undertow.

As for people, how about...

- "I think you've **underestimated** (the depth of) his character".

Comment: @LittleEva  You're right, "dive" requires "overestimate" (reminds me of the spanish film "The Sea Inside").   but what I actually meant was "get into the water".  I'll edit.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

- Complex

  > Not easy to analyse or understand. (Oxford)
- Intricate

  > Very complicated or detailed. (Oxford)
- Profound

  > (Of a person or statement) having or showing great knowledge or insight. (Oxford)

Or as Tushar already mentioned:

- There's more to someone than meets the eye

  > A person or situation is more complex or interesting than they appear. (Oxford)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking maybe in terms of "Language Arts", **dynamic**. Like a dynamic vs flat character.

Comment: or confounding.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It would be great if you could give an example of the word being used in this way - do you have any sources or references?